# Need help to short out this error Error:(32, 43) error: incompatible types: Tab1Fragment cannot be converted to Context?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am working on a small app which has 4 tabs with four different Fragment Each fragment contain separate list view But when i applied listView in my firstFragment it shows me this error 
My AdapterCode is 
package androidthirst.company.abhi.totalenglish;

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] MainTopic, String[] img, String[] description) {
    super(context,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView,MainTopic);
    this.context=context;
    this.MainTopic=MainTopic;
    this.img=img;
    this.description=description;

}
@Override
public View getView(int  position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View row=  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
   TextView imageView= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  TextView textView1= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   TextView textView2= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    for (int i =1;i<=position+1;i++) {
        imageView.setText("" +i);

    }
    //imageView.setText(img[position]);
     textView1.setText(MainTopic[position]);
    textView2.setText(description[position]);
    return row;
}
```

}

My firstFragment code is in which i want to display my firstListview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1,container,false);

    Resources res= getResources();
    mainTopic=res.getStringArray(R.array.MainTopic);
    mainDescription=res.getStringArray(R.array.DescriptionContent);
    listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,mainTopic,image1,mainDescription);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    return view;


}



}
```

Comment: Already seen it but it does not help me so please help

Comment: @Ironman this is not duplicate - in the link you provided there are import mistake and here is inheritance misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

`MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,mainTopic,image1,mainDescription);`

change to

```
MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(),mainTopic,image1,mainDescription);
```

Your MyAdapter is expecting `Context` as parameter of it's constructor. Providing `this` inside `Fragment` cause Incompatible Types because `Fragment` is `Object`, while `Activity` is extending `Context`, thus, providing `this` from `Activity` will work but from `Fragment` you need to provide the containing `Activity` context by `getActivity()`.

Comment: this means your phone is disconnected from the computer, try reconnecting the cable and re-run build